# Storing timetable availability in SQL table

Tags: sql, database

I'm playing around with a database idea at the moment. It's likely not going to be deployed in any sort of fashion and is more of a learning experience.

It's meant to simplify the collection and handling of tutor information for a bunch of classes at the university I went to. I worked part time in an office that organised tutors for a handful of classes each semester.

I've got a number of questions, but the one that's causing me a problem at the moment is how I can store the availability of each tutor. I'm considering 3 options at the moment, and I'm looking for feedback on the pros and cons of each from a technical perspective.

**Background:** 
Tutor information is stored in a "tutor" table (tutorID references this) and the previous availability must be able to be recalled. Tutor availability is discrete (hourly), and constant throughout a semester.

**Option 1:**

```
Table: Availability
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---+---+---+----+---+
| avID (PK) | tutorID | year  |  sem  | M | T | W | Th | F |
|           |         | (int) | (int) |    (all strings)   |
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---+---+---+----+---+
```

In this table, availaiblity is stored in a string (08,09,10,13,14 represents 8am, 9am, 10am, 1pm and 2pm).

Data could be reclaimed with

```
SELECT * FROM Availability WHERE tutorID=0001 AND year=2013 AND sem=1
```

And to see who's available

```
SELECT * FROM Availability WHERE AND year=2013 AND sem=1 AND M LIKE '%08%'
```

**Option 2:**

```
Table: Availability
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+
| avID (PK) | tutorID | year  |  sem  | availability |
|           |         | (int) | (int) |     (set)    |
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+
```

In this layout, the availability column is stored as the SET datatype in mysql, with the options being every combination of Mon through Friday and every time from 8 till 4 (M08, M09... Th14, F16 etc etc). This works out to 45 acceptable values. This is the one that I'm currently leaning towards, but I don't know much about the SET datatype.

Data could be reclaimed with

```
SELECT * FROM Availability WHERE tutorID=0001 AND year=2013 AND sem=1
```

And to see who's available

```
SELECT * FROM Availability WHERE AND year=2013 AND sem=1 
                AND FIND_IN_SET('M09',availability) > 0
```

**Option 3:**

```
Table: Availability
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| avID (PK) | tutorID | year  |  sem  |  day  | time  |
|           |         | (int) | (int) | (int) | (int) |
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

In this option, there is a single row for each tutor each year and each timeslot.

Data could be reclaimed with

```
SELECT * FROM Availability WHERE year=2013 AND sem=2 AND tutorID=0001
```

Availability with

```
SELECT * FROM Availability WHERE year=2013 AND sem=2 AND day=3 AND time=14
```

Anyway... Thanks for reading through all of that. Hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on this. I think that it basically will boil down to a best-practice type of question. Unless there's something that I've missed entirely!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your listed options are [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Basically normalizing, and one of the main points and benefits of relational database technology, is avoiding the storage of redundant information.

### Option 1

You were not clear about the requirement, but I'm assuming a tutor may be available more than one hour per day. That would make Option 1 awkward, or a poor fit because you would have to have multiple rows to cover multiple sessions in a single day. The other columns values would be duplicated across rows – that kind of repetition means a violation of normalization.

Also, choosing text as the data type for the start time is probably not optimal. If the sessions always start on the hour, then you are dealing with hour numbers. If dealing with numbers, store them as numbers (as a general rule). If the sessions may not *always* start on the hour, then you are dealing with time values. Same general rule, store them as a Time data type.

Choosing int as data type for year is probably not clear. Usually an academic year is something like "2013-2014".

### Option 2

In Option 2, stuffing multiple points of data into a single field is definitely not normalized. While your query would work it has at least two shortcomings. One is performance; typically searching a multi-value field like that will be relatively slow. But more importantly, violating normalization almost always leads to painting yourself into a corner. What if you want to tie additional values to each of those time slots — you can't because you don't have access to each time slot when they are smashed together.

### Option 3

In Option 3, you are getting closer to a normalized design. But notice how multiple fields will be repeated together (`year` and `sem`)? Again that kind of duplication is a flag for a violation of normalization.

### Generalize

When designing, generally it is a good habit to broaden or generalize your thinking. For example, are sessions *always* forever going to start on the hour and last one hour? Not likely. So it may be smart to use a Time value rather than an hour number. Another example, "semester" – not all schools use semesters and even those that do (yours) may change. So it may be smart to generalize to "term" and not make assumptions related to semesters. On the other hand, don't over-generalize or else you can fall into a meaningless mess of a design or fall into analysis-paralysis.

### Normalize

To normalize, look for the "things", the stuff that may take an action, or stuff that "owns" other stuff. We call these entities.

You've already identified the `tutor` as a separate entity. Good.

I see another: `term` (semester). That repeating of 'year' and 'sem' is the clue. Such repetition is avoided by moving those values into another table. That table is for the entity of 'term'. Another clue that separate table is correct is the idea that we may well want to tie other information to the 'term' table, such as the term's start date and length (or stop date). Such additional data certainly should not be repeated across all our 'availability' rows. Such data should be stored once in a single row in `term` table.

### My Design

So my initial design would look like this diagram.
[image: Diagram of three tables in Many-to-Many relationship, Tutor, Availability, and Term]

This relationship is [Many-to-Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29). Each tutor may be available in multiple terms, and each term may have multiple tutors. A many-to-many is a problem in a relational design, and is *always* resolved with a third "bridge" or "junction" table. Many-to-many and bridge tables are quite common in databases designed for business contexts.

Here, the bridge table between them, is `availibility_`. That bridge table is a child table to both, and carries each parent's primary key (a [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)). Tip: when I place parents (blue here) higher vertically than children (orange here), and I notice the "bird body with raised wings" pattern of a parent on either side, then I recognize a many-to-many relationship exists between the parents.

---

By the way, there are times to violate normalization. We call that "to dernormalize". Usually the goal is related to performance. But denormalize only after you have consulted with another experienced database designer, and when you have very good reasons, clearly know the price you are paying, and thoroughly document the violation for the edification of those who may later take your place.

Comment: I've heard about database normalisation - I did a bit of reading on it before I asked this question. My 3rd option originally had the term and semester fields abstracted to another table, but I figured that by doing that I was just making it overly complicated.

Thanks so much for your input, though! I'll have a go at doing this (after my exams) and let you know how I went!

Comment: Option 3 could work. Context is everything. If this were a quick-and-dirty project, you could go with Option 3. If there were a serious project, with the likelihood of growing to represent more of the business, then normalizing with the 3 tables I suggested would pay off in the long-term. Technically, you can start with Option 3 and later add the "term_" table while moving the data around. That's called "database refactoring". Thanks for your thoughtful question; should prove useful to others.

Comment: If you're interested, the format I've decided to try out is [here](http://i.imgur.com/km10ptm.png). It's not completely finished yet, and I'm not sure if this is clear or not without some context, but I think it gives an idea of what I'm trying to do! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: FYI - the original poster mentioned "a best-practice type of question". Actually, database normalization is not a matter of "best-practice" in the sense of opinion or habit. Normalization is actually an academic subject, proven with mathematics, and entire textbooks of coverage. [Dr. Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd) was a mathematician who had the grand insight that a narrow niche of the math world could be applied to the problem of representing data commonly found in the domain of business. Normalization is the only true engineering in software; the rest is art not science.